# Calling variables from Class to another

Tags: python

I find myself in this situation:

```
class C2(x2, f2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(x2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

And:

```
class C1(x1, f1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(x1, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        text = self.FMB.text()
```

And I would like to be able to pass the text variable to class `C2`. I have tried to use the following method:

```
class C2(x2, f2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(x2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        def f3(t):
            var = t
            self.v2.setText(t)

# Here the variable 'text' from C1 is assigned to a lineedit in C2

class C1(x1, f1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(x1, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        text = self.FMB.text()
        C2.f3(text)
```

But it is not possible to carry out the commented assignment. How can I do it?

Comment: `f3` is not a class function. You cannot call `C2.f3(text)`. And if you want to set anything within that instance of it, `C2.v2` needs to be an instance variable, not a class variable. What are `x1,x2,f1,f2`? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, thanks. They are parameters for loading ui files from Designer.

Answer (score 1):

As @cricket_007 mentioned in the comments, you can't call `C2.f3()` since `f3` is not a class function, but it is a method of `C2` which is different.

So what you can do.

1) Call `f3` as a method:

```
class C2:
    def f3(self, t):
        ...
```

And then use it like:

```
C2().f3(text)
```

Or

2) Make `f3` a class function and use it as it is in your code:

```
class C2:
    @classmethod
    def f3(cls, t):
        ....
```

Comment: Applying this methodology it was possible to call the variable of the class C1, however, when using this variable to assign it to the lineEdit it is not collected by this object (lineEdit). Is it possible that within the 'self' function it is not considered as the object declared in said Class C2?

Comment: @Patrick, Could you update your original question adding the changes you made to your code and point where "lineEdit" is not being assigned to the variable you want? For now I can't see what it might possibly be. Or, for the frst problem, if it was solved, you can skip the update for this first question and ask a new question about the new problem.

Comment: I apologize for my delay in answering. I will comment on the results obtained once applied. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a little confusing.  Do you want to pass the text to the *class* C2 (meaning every instance of C2 will have identical text), or to an *instance* of C2  (meaning each instance can have its own text value)?

Assuming you meant the latter, you'll have to change `f3()` to add a `self` parameter.  You'll also need to pass an *instance* of C2 into `C1.__init__()`

Comment: Thank you. I will apply the options presented and comment on the results obtained.